# System.Web has only 3 assemblies available - .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, using, system.web

I need to use the System.Web.Script.Serialization assembly as well as some others from System.Web, but when I type `using System.Web.` it only gives me 3 options of assemblies, none of which are what I'm looking for. I'm using .Net 4.5. Thanks.

Comment: Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to your project:

```
System.Web.Extensions
```